# How to read/write data via BLE in Mbed OS 6?

Tags: embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, mbed

I have an Android smartphone and a Discovery L475VG IoT development board. I am trying send/receive data (both directions) via BLE. I have consulted a good bit of documentation (although much of it is out of date for Mbed OS 6) and I have been trying to analyze what's going on in the GattServer characteristicUpdate and characteristicWrite example codes. [See here](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-ble)

The two example codes work for what they're supposed to demonstrate, but they seem to go about implementing reads and writes differently, or maybe I am just not following what's going on?

If it isn't obvious, I am not super familiar with the BLE stack as a whole, and particularly not the mbed implementation of it. I previously made an Arduino-based system that accomplished the same goal I'm trying to here, but I am having trouble figuring out more complicated, lower-level library that mbed provides.

The read() and write() functions, which seem like the obvious things I would need, appear to be private functions, so I assume there is more to it than that and, naturally, mbed Studio doesn't just let me call them from main().

Can someone point me in the right direction of where to start?

Comment: The example you want to start with is BLE_GattServer_CharacteristicWrite. Install it on your development board and use a generic BLE scanner such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to write to the offered characteristic. The GattServer is your peripheral and offers characteristics to write and/or read. The example offers a writable characteristic

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan In the CharacteristicWrite example code, I can see the data received to the mbed board, but how do I change the value being sent from the mbed board? I see that I can change the starting value, but how do I update this in other parts of the code? It seems because the variable is declared with a private scope it is not addressable in other sections of the code.

Comment: The example code for CharacteristicWrite, as the name suggests, only offers one characteristic that you can write to. The written value will be printed on to the serial console of your development board. If you want to read values from the board you have to add another, readable characteristic. You might want to look at the [CharacteristicUpdates](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-ble/blob/development/BLE_GattServer_CharacteristicUpdates) example which shows how to update values at runtime and send notifications to your client

Comment: The one characteristic declared is a ReadWrite though, so should it not be able to do both? It does read a value, I'm just confused on how to change the value that it's sending. I added a public method that is called within onDataWritten that assigns a new value to _writable_characteristic, however that approach doesn't seem to work as NRF connect doesn't do anything when I press read after I write a value initially.

Comment: The characteristic is defined as a `ReadWriteGattCharacteristic`. Since the code does not change the value you are simply reading back the value you wrote into it, which appears as "doesn't do anything" since the value does not change. Its hard to tell whats going wrong in your approach without seeing code though. I'm going to prepare something for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have figured it out, thanks to Michael Kotzjan for the help:

```
    virtual void onDataWritten(const GattWriteCallbackParams &params)
    {
        if ((params.handle == _writable_characteristic->getValueHandle()) && (params.len == 1)) {
            printf("New characteristic value written: %x\r\n", *(params.data));
            // Set value of characteristic to value * 2
            uint8_t temp = *params.data * 2;
            _server->write(_writable_characteristic->getValueHandle(),&temp, sizeof(temp),false);
        }
    }
```

When the phone sends a byte to the mbed board, the mbed board sets the write characteristic to double the value that was received. The pointer stuff was a bit confusing, but this works now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify the [BLE_GattServer_CharacteristicWrite](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-ble/blob/development/BLE_GattServer_CharacteristicWrite/source/main.cpp) to allow you to set the characteristic value after writing. This approach is **completely untested** since I don't have access to a mbed developer board.

```cpp
/* mbed Microcontroller Library
 * Copyright (c) 2006-2013 ARM Limited
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

#include <events/mbed_events.h>
#include "ble/BLE.h"
#include "gatt_server_process.h"
#include "mbed-trace/mbed_trace.h"

static EventQueue event_queue(/* event count */ 10 * EVENTS_EVENT_SIZE);

class GattServerDemo : ble::GattServer::EventHandler {

    const static uint16_t EXAMPLE_SERVICE_UUID         = 0xA000;
    const static uint16_t WRITABLE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = 0xA001;

public:
    GattServerDemo()
    {
        const UUID uuid = WRITABLE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID;
        _writable_characteristic = new ReadWriteGattCharacteristic<uint8_t> (uuid, &_characteristic_value);

        if (!_writable_characteristic) {
            printf("Allocation of ReadWriteGattCharacteristic failed\r\n");
        }
    }

    ~GattServerDemo()
    {
    }

    void start(BLE &ble, events::EventQueue &event_queue)
    {
        const UUID uuid = EXAMPLE_SERVICE_UUID;
        GattCharacteristic* charTable[] = { _writable_characteristic };
        GattService example_service(uuid, charTable, 1);

        _server = &ble.gattServer();
        _server.addService(example_service);

        _server.setEventHandler(this);

        printf("Example service added with UUID 0xA000\r\n");
        printf("Connect and write to characteristic 0xA001\r\n");
    }

private:
    /**
     * This callback allows the LEDService to receive updates to the ledState Characteristic.
     *
     * @param[in] params Information about the characterisitc being updated.
     */
    virtual void onDataWritten(const GattWriteCallbackParams &params)
    {
        if ((params.handle == _writable_characteristic->getValueHandle()) && (params.len == 1)) {
            printf("New characteristic value written: %x\r\n", *(params.data));
            // Set value of characteristic to value * 2
            _writable_characteristic->set(*_server, params.data * 2);
        }
    }

private:
    ReadWriteGattCharacteristic<uint8_t> *_writable_characteristic = nullptr;
    uint8_t _characteristic_value = 0;
    GattServer *_server = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    mbed_trace_init();

    BLE &ble = BLE::Instance();

    printf("\r\nGattServer demo of a writable characteristic\r\n");

    GattServerDemo demo;

    /* this process will handle basic setup and advertising for us */
    GattServerProcess ble_process(event_queue, ble);

    /* once it's done it will let us continue with our demo*/
    ble_process.on_init(callback(&demo, &GattServerDemo::start));

    ble_process.start();

    return 0;
}
```

This should set the characteristic to the written value * 2 when reading afterwards.